# Box shadow disappears when overflow is set

Tags: html, css, overflow

Referring to this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2crwskzt/

I have a table and I set overflow-y as auto on tbody. But somehow doing so will make the box shadow on the left and right of the box disappear. Why is this happening and how to fix this?

html:

```
<table class="scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
table.scroll {
    width: 100%; /* Optional */
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead { display: block; }

thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}

table.scroll tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

tbody td, thead th {
    width: 20%; /* Optional */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red
}

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: you need to add some space in between the shadowed element and it parent : https://jsfiddle.net/vmjgd15z/